# Can´t execute a cron with whenever in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, delayed-job, whenever

So I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I´m doing a simples crontab. I'm using 'whenever' with 'rbenv'.

```
    env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
    set :output, './log/cron.log'
    set :environment, 'development'
    every 1.minute do
      runner "puts 'Ola mundo!'"
    end
```

crontab -l

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario/config/schedule.rb at: 2024-02-05 14:23:27 +0000
PATH=/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/bin:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@13/bin:/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin

* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''puts '\''\'\'''\''Ola mundo!'\''\'\'''\'''\'' >> ./log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario/config/schedule.rb at: 2024-02-05 14:23:27 +0000
```

and I don't know why I'm receiving this error:

```
cut: /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario/.ruby-version: Operation not permitted
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:45:in `filter!'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:284:in `matching_specs'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:272:in `find_spec_for_exe'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

If I run this command in the project terminal

```
bin/rails runner -e development "puts 'Ola mundo!'" >>./log/cron.log
```

The command run without a problem!

I'm using

```
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin23]
```

My final idea is to create a job to get data from the web and put it on Postgres database (this is already done). And I need this to execute everyday.
So I thought about combine gem 'whenever' with gem 'delayed_job_active_record'. am I in the right way?

Comment: My guess is that when the cron job runs it's running under a user that does not have the right permissions.

Comment: @HectorCorrea I'm running in the only user that exists in this computer so I think I should have all permission no?

Comment: I noticed that the error message that you included points to Ruby 2.6 but you are actually using Ruby 3.1.2. This would lead me to believe that, as Fabio said below, the cronjob is not running with the proper configuration. When you are logged in you account has different settings than when the cronjob runs. In this case your account is configured to use version 3.1 of Ruby but when the cronjon runs is not picking up those same configurations and that's why it shows as using Ruby 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Check (and add to your question) your crontab entry. Running Ruby scripts via CRON is not a trivial task, specially if you use Bundler, non-standard gems and/or RVM. You'll have to make sure the environment variables are correct, and most likely will have to switch the current working directory to a writable one.

To check your current crontab entry, use `crontab -l`. To edit it, use `crontab -e`.

A good practice when running more complex scripts on CRON is to write a wrapper script in `sh` or `bash`. There's a lot of references about it here on SO.

If you are using RVM, their website has a dedicated page with instructions on how to make it work with CRON, check their website for more info: https://rvm.io/deployment/cron

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I add more things to the question can you check out?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem but I think this is not the best way.
So this code

```
set :output, './log/cron.log'
set :environment, 'development'

every 1.minute do
  runner 'puts "Ola mundo!"'
end
```

Was creating this crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''puts "Ola mundo!"'\'' >> ./log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

So this cron wasn't getting the rbenv version correct so I add this line

```
set :path, '/Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario'
job_type :rbenv_rails_runner, 'cd :path && /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle exec bin/rails runner -e :environment ":task" :output'

every 1.minute do
  rbenv_rails_runner 'puts "Ola mundo!"'
end
```

and this way I m telling the cron to get the rbenv version.

this creates this crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/pedrodiogo/Desktop/branch_csv_diario && /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/3.1.2/bin/bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development "puts \"Ola mundo!\"" >> ./log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

I think this is not the right way! Hope getting some feedback from seniors developers!